# How to set django model field by name?

Tags: django, django-models

This seems like it should be dead simple, so I must be missing something. I just want to set the value of a field in my model instance by name. Say I have:

```
class Foo(Model):
  bar = CharField()

f = Foo()
```

I want to set the value of bar by name, not by accessing the field. So something like:

```
f.fields['bar'] = 'BAR"
```

instead of

```
f.bar = 'BAR'
```

I've tried setattr but it doesn't persist the value in the database. I also tried going through _meta.fields but got various errors along the way.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you modify the value via `setattr`, you need to remember to save the model after modifying it. I've been bitten in the past where I changed the values but forgot to save the model, and got the same result.

```
setattr(f, 'bar', 'BAR')
f.save()
```

Answer (score 21):

We may have to see more code.

```
setattr(f, 'bar', 'BAR')
```

should work as this is how Django does it internally.

Make sure you are calling 'save', as well.