# django access model object fields on run-time

Tags: django

I have a list of fields for an object:

```
fields = ('title', 'first_name', 'last_name)
```

Now I want to access the fields of my object on runtime, without harcoding it like this.

```
myobject.title
```

What I'm searching for is something like this:

```
myobject.getFieldValue('title')
```

Is there a method like this in django? I did not find one.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545645/how-to-set-django-model-field-by-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a Django method, but a standard Python builtin:

```
getattr(myobject, 'title')
```

Answer (score 0):

But if you can access the attribute of a object by something like this `myobject.title`, why do you want a manager (in case of a database query) or a function to do this?

Comment: I think there are some use-cases where you want to access the value of a field without hardprinting it. My use-case is the following: I have a view that presents all Contacts in a table. This table is created based on a list, called: HEADERS_CONTACT. I'm using this list in different views and functions. One function is export contacts. Here I want to export the same values as defined in HEADERS_CONTACT. Thus if I decide to present more details of a contact in the contact overview I will change the HEADERS_CONTACT list and can be sure that my export function will export the values accordingly.

Comment: We have some MixIn classes we use across a large number of database models. Most *but not all* of them have a particular field (e.g. `title`) so in the methods of the MixIn class we have to use hasattr() to make sure it will work, and then getattr(), normally with a default value supplied.