# Iterating through a data list and edit an object's attribute based on the list

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I would like to retrieve a list of PUT data, iterate through this list and update the object based on the attributes in the list. My codes are as follows:

```
         property_id = data['id']
            if property_id:
                property_selected = Property.objects.get(id=property_id)
                if property_selected:
                    for d in data:
                        property_selected.d = data[d]
                    property_selected.save()
```

However, this will not work as it will save the value as property_selected.d instead of property_selected.name when the attribute is called name. Does anyone have any idea how i should solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (with [`iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) and [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)):

```
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    setattr(property_selected, key, value)
```

But you should probably limit the fields that are allowed to be edited:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    if key in ['foo_field', 'bar_field']:
        setattr(property_selected, key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an attribute by name you can use the setattr method of a django model instance

`setattr(property_selected, d, data[d])`

Source: [How to set django model field by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545645/how-to-set-django-model-field-by-name)

Comment: And to get an attribute dynamically you can use getattr(property_selected, d)

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin function [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
for d in data:
    setattr(property_selected, d, data[d])
```

There are [a number of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/setattr/hot) using setattr that are illuminating reading.