# How use dynamic attributes at python/django

Tags: python, django

In PHP I can use `$obj->$my_attr` for example. How I can make this in Django?

My model:

```
codigo_barras = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u'Código de barras'), max_length=150 , blank=True)

codigo_interno = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u'Código de interno'), max_length=150, blank=True)    

my_dynamic_field =  'codigo_barras'
```

I try make:

```
produto.my_dynamic_field = item['valor']

produto.save()
```

Comment: Does this question anwser yours too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545645/how-to-set-django-model-field-by-name note that setattr in not django specific, you can use it on plain python objects

Comment: Work for me! Thanks