# How to manually populate Django model data for insert

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, model

I'm trying to store a list of timings for a speed test.

All timings are serialized clientside and sent to the server via ajax.

**Model:**

```
class SpeedTest(models.Model):
    t1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    t2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    t3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    t100+ = ...
```

**View:**

```
def save(request):
    results = json.loads(request.POST.get('results'))

    speed_test = SpeedTest.objects.create()

    for result in results:
        key = "t"+str(result['key'])
        speed_test.key = value

    speed_test.save()
```

Where `results` has the form:

```
results[0]['key'] = 1
results[0]['value'] = 0.539
results[1]['key'] = 2
results[1]['value'] = 0.654
results[2]['key'] = 3
results[2]['value'] = 0.426
...
...
...
results[100+]...
```

I am trying to loop through all the `t1 - t100+` values and add them to my model object. I.e a loop to do:

```
speed_test.t1 = 0.539
speed_test.t2 = 0.654
speed_test.t3 = 0.426
...
etc
```

These lines are not doing the job.

```
key = "t"+str(result['key'])
speed_test.key = value
```

**What is the correct way to do this?**

Comment: Well, `setattr(speed_test, key, value)` is the "correct" way to write what you're trying to do in those two lines that *are not doing the job*... but whether it's the correct approach overall is another thing...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you. And briefly, what overall approaches should I investigate? I'm intentionally not using Django forms, etc.

Comment: Hard to say... this is one of those "always depends on what you're doing and constraints" are... however, having a model with 100(+) columns strikes me as possibly another model itself with a foreign key for instance...

Comment: @JonClements In context, we are measuring 100+ response times for stimuli and as far as I know, need the data in tabular form per test, for statistical analysis. Not a complex model, just lots of data. I appreciate the feedback and will consider your ideas and investigate suitable alternatives.

Comment: It's still "tabular" - it's just stored in a format whereby DBMS's can efficiently process it and you can still present it in tabular form if needed... but in a normalised form you don't have to worry about however many tests exists per test (thus a fixed number of columns etc...) or remodelling the DB later if you wish to add further columns etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is question is answered within a different context here [How to set django model field by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1545668/8226216).

To explain it a bit further and with your code as example:

Construct the Fieldname via `key = "t"+str(result['key'])`,

Set the desired value via `setattr(speed_test, key, result['value'])`

And after the loop, don't forget to call `speed_test.save()`.

One personal Recomendation:

If you are looking forward to more work correlated with AJAX/JSON  you might want to consider [Django-REST-Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for it's Serializer which handle such stuff quite good for simple/flat cases (you current problem would be in such category).

NOTE:
In your given example data

```
results[0]['key'] = 1
results[0]['value'] = 0.539
results[1]['key'] = 2
results[1]['value'] = 0.654
results[2]['key'] = 2
results[2]['value'] = 0.426
```

does the third result really OVERWRITE the second ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: DRF will work quite nicely if appropriate models/methods are setup... for this case though - it's a bit overkill and would still require the same amount of work even if adhoc'ing it using json response and django base models/post forms etc...

Comment: You are definately right but thats why i declared it as personal recomendation with the remark on "if you have to deal with more stuff of this kind".